# Does VB.Net support partial interface to prepare the repository pattern?

Tags: vb.net, interface, partial

Does vb.net support Partial interface contacts in web service development ? I worked in c# where the syntax is  `public partial interface IRepository{}` . Where partial is not supported by VB.net. if yes, please provide the syntax for the same.

Comment: Based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfzd5350.aspx) it looks like it only works with classes and structs in VB.NET.  C# does support it for interfaces - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx)

Comment: oh. Thanks for the information. seems module wise development for repository pattern is challenge in vb.net then.

Comment: Even if you did have it, you still would not use it.  Partial interfaces don't scale properly, they can't span across assemblies.  Use interface inheritance.

Comment: absolutely agree, but to achieve future enhancements or to attach new functionality or module it will better to add separate partial interface. interface inheritance is one of base development strategy. where adding partial seems good concept to work with large team within repository like pattern.

Comment: Apparently support will be added in [VB.NET 14 / VS2015](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status).

Answer (score 1):

This was available in C#, but not VB.Net. As of the VS 2015 (and the Roslyn compiler) release, it has been added for VB.NET.